# mysql trigger - how to add a record id after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a logging table:

```
mysql> desc MyLog;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Aud_ID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Rec_ID      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AudObj      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| User_ID     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AudType     | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ChangedOn   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have a trigger for "after insert":

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_Images_add
    AFTER INSERT ON Images_TST
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO AuditLog
       SET Rec_ID = NEW.Image_ID,  
           AudType = 'ADDED', 
           AudObj = 'Images', 
           User_ID = NEW.employee_ID,
           changedon = NOW();
    END;
```

On "after insert" when we add a new record to our table, my Rec_ID (which doesn't exist yet, until is added = 0), but after its added, **I want to capture that "NEW" Rec_ID and insert that into the table.** Can I do this within this same trigger?

Here's my output:

```
mysql> select * from MyLog;
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| Aud_ID   | Rec_ID    | AudObj      | User_ID | AudType   | ChangedOn           |
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
|     1003 |         0 | Images      | 445     | ADDED     | 2014-10-28 09:09:42 |
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Here's the output I am looking for:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| Aud_ID   | Rec_ID    | AudObj      | User_ID | AudType   | ChangedOn           |
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
|     1003 |         0 | Images      | 445     | ADDED     | 2014-10-28 09:09:42 |
|     1004 |         22| Images      | 445     | NEWREC_ID | 2014-10-28 09:09:42 |
+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it the way you are trying. Just modify the trigger body a little like below using `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME .. VALUES` construct

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_Images_add
    AFTER INSERT ON Images_TST
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO MyLog(Rec_ID, AudType, AudObj, User_ID, changedon)
       VALUES(NEW.Image_ID, 'ADDED', 'Images', NEW.employee_ID, NOW());
    END;
```

Comment: Somehow, I'm getting a syntax error for using this function.

Comment: @oramel, see edited answer. That was incorrect before.

Comment: thanks for your help. I got the syntax to create with your construct. However, i'm still in this same dilemma where my `rec_id=0` using LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: There is a small catch which I corrected in my answer. In your trigger you are doing `INSERT INTO AuditLog` but you are trying to do `select * from MyLog`. Those are two different tables. Also, don't use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. That's incorrect. Use the code in my edited answer and it should work fine.